# How to access a method of a class running inside a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to call the "checkTime" method of the "Timer" class from outside this class but that is not working... is this the right way ? how can I fix this? I am using threads

```
class Timer implements Runnable{

        private boolean running;
        private int time = 0;

        public Timer(){

            time = 10;
            running = false;
        }

        public boolean isRunning(){
            return  running;
        }

        public void checkTime(){
            if(isRunning()){
                System.out.println("Timer is at: "+ time/1000 + " seconds");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                running = true;
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                }
                running = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

In the other class i have something like this

````
Thread timer;
timer = new Thread(new Timer());

                //check timer
                if(cooking){
                    timer.checkTime();

                } else{
                    System.out.println("The timer is set to: " + timer + " seconds");
                }
                break;```
````

Comment: Define "that is not working". Are you getting a runtime error? Compilation Error?

Comment: `timer` is of type Thread. Thread doesn't have any method named `checkTime()`. The method you're trying to call is in the class Timer. So you need a variable of type Timer to be able to call it.

Comment: By not working I meant that I can not access the checkTime(). I changed the description may be it makes more sense now.

Comment: @CliveCharles / @JB Nizet - `timer.checkTime();` : isn't the `timer` a varible of Timer?

Comment: From your own code: `Thread timer;`. So, you see, its type is Thread, not Timer. Threading and concurrency are very, very, very complex matters. If you don't master variables and types yet, it's probably way too soon to start using threads.

Comment: Seems like, you have not written `catch` or `finally` with your `try` block.

Comment: @GanesaVijayakumar Don't undo OPs modification of the question for "formatting" reasons. Your changes have been reverted.

Comment: @Andreas, No, I didn't. Looks like it's conflicted with the recent changes from `Clive Charles`

Comment: @Andreas that edit was older than the OP’s modifications but ended up hanging in the review queue for almost half an hour. And even the reviewers didn’t see that there was another edit (the diff was shown based on the original version). That’s why it got approved, eventually. It’s Stackoverflow’s fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a variable of the Timer object before you instantiate a the Thread object.

Example:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
Thread thread = new Thread(timer);
// get the checkTime() value here
System.out.println(timer.checkTime());
```

You really need to watch out for concurrency issues as you have multiple threads managing the same variables (`int time` and `boolean running`).